# How can KNN algorithm be applied to categorical variables?

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn, categorical-data

I am working on data set where most of the variables are categorical variables. some variables have even 5 categories. Is it possible to implement knn algorithm in a situation like this? If so, how can I proceed with these categorical variables? Do I have to normalize them? I am using R and it would be a help if someone could direct me to a source.

Comment: How would you define a distance function for categorical variables?

Answer (score 4):

Your first step would be to decide on a distance/dissimilarity function between your observations.

One option is to transform your categorical variables into dummy binary variables and then calculate the Jaccard distance between each row pair. [Here](http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Similarity/BinaryVariables.html) is a simple tutorial for these steps.

Once you have a distance defined you can proceed with the KNN algorithm as usual. I'm not sure if there are any packages implementing this in R already or if you should program this yourself. Shouldn't be that complicated